# How to override overridden class -- CSS

Tags: css

We're using bootstrap.
We've override the '.label' class so that it's square, to fit the websites' design.

However, now I want to use the original '.label' from bootstrap, with the round corners.

Current css code

```
.label {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

**How could I override the overridden class?**

---

Okay, so a lot of your answers were a possibility, but since we were overriding the (bootstrap) 'label' class from the start, I didn't have the css settings to recreate the label.

However, what I ended up with (same .css settings as the bootstrap one) is:

```
.label-details {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 100%;
   font-weight: 100;
   line-height: 1.2;
   padding: .2em .6em .3em;
   color: #666666;
   white-space: normal;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
   box-sizing: initial;
   background-color: #f0ad4e;
   border-radius: 6px 6px;
}
```

I agree that this isn't the best method, but we're (probably) only going to use a label like this only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a parent class like

```
.parent .label { /* styles */}
```

or

```
.label.style1 { /* styles */}
```

Comment: I like the `.label.style1` option. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Paramone your html will then look like class="label style1" and your css maybe only needs .style1 {}

Answer (score 2):

try to write styles in this way:

```
.label.rounded {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

then add class **rounded** on each label that need to be with rounded corners

```
 <label class="label rounded">...</label>
```

As a result you will not rewrite bootstrap label class

Comment: @Pete, no problem, did it )

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `:not()` and apply an id to the label where you not to add custom style. just like that.

### Using Id

#### CSS

```
.label:not(#withboot) {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<label class="label">with custom style</label>
<label class="label" id="withboot">with bootstrap style</label>
```

[see here](http://www.bootply.com/AaYVfp9IEa)

### Using Class

#### CSS

you can also use class instead of id:

```
.label:not(.withboot) {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<label class="label">with custom style</label>
<label class="label withboot">with bootstrap style</label>
```

[see here](http://www.bootply.com/GZVGanSleg)

Comment: It`s bad idea to add same id on multiple elements

Comment: @Kison you can use class intead of id

Comment: yep, you are right, but then will better if you make your example with class )

Answer (score 0):

I would not touch original Bootstrap classes and add my own custom stylesheet that is loaded after Bootstrap css for overriding purposes, which includes a class such as '.label-custom'.
Example:

```
.label-custom {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```